# How do I give "export as png" option in vega chart when used in kibana or used outside vege editor

Tags: kibana, vega, vega-lite

I have average knowledge about vega charts and I want to know how we can give export option in vega charts. I have not been able to find anything in the documentation for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The standard "Export in PNG" option is controlled by the "actions" option in Vega-Embed: https://github.com/vega/vega-embed#options